# Why does "My Calendar" list in Outlook keep duplicating/creating calendars that show up every day even after I delete them?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

Outlook shows 20+ calendars in the "My Calendar" list (pic1) which I delete each day individually so I only see the handful I need. They always show back up the next time I open Outlook although some of them don't have a delete option. The calendars are all maintained by our IT dept, but they have no idea why it's happening either. I have a section called Team (pic2) with my boss and her direct reports' calendars and Shared Calendars which only has my boss in it. It's almost as if Outlook is replicating calendars each night that don't exist.

What steps I've taken:
Checked online version and it shows just the handful I need.
IT Dept did an Office online repair
Rebooted router
Rebooted computer

I just want that long list gone. It never leaves and it invites friends every day! Ack!!

[image: Outlook: My Calendars list]

[image: Outlook: Calendars]

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, i notice that the issue only occurs in Outlook desktop client but not in web mail. If you are using Cache mode, it's suggested that you could disable it and switch to online mode and then remove the calendars.

If the issue disappears, please create a new profile and re-enable Cache mode.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.